# how to install software to a VM using chocolatey

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, chocolatey

Now I am struggling with install software to vagrant Vm. I took some file from this [Link](https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey-handsonlab) but it didn’t work.
After create the vagrant box. I run the **vagrant up** command to create the VM it worked. After that I edit the file and run **vagrant provision**   then it give few errors

[image]

This is the vagrant file edited part

[image]

This is my VM located. And same files located on the "C:\vagrant\"

[image]

i want to install the software which is located on my local chocolaty repository. Or run the nuget i Edited(after download from chocolatey cloud server and edited which pointed to my local EXE location), which are located on my local server

Answer (score 0):

It may help to start with the entire working example and then remove parts and see how those items are linked or used and make adjustments from there. The error is telling you what is wrong, you may want to inspect that further because the error messages are very helpful.